# How to style width of n number of divisions in Angular dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am building a sorting visualizer on angular. What I want to do is generate a visualized array of random numbers in the form of bar representation using divisions. The width of each division corresponds to the value of the array on that particular index. 
For example if arr[0]=70, then the width of div id='bar0' will be 70% . This visualization will be generated when I click on the button generate an array, which when followed by a click on sort button which sorts the whole array.

but it does not work that way, instead, I keep getting error in my developer console.
Here is my code for app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  str: string = "";
  strr: string = "";
  temp: number = 0;
  inputtext: string = "hey";
  index: number = 0;
  arr = [];
  inputtext1: string = this.inputtext;
  title: any;
  constructor() {
    console.log("running");
  }
  generateArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
      this.arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    }
    this.arrayfy();
  }
  arrayfy() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
      this.str = "bar" + i;
      document.getElementById(this.str).style.width = this.arr[i] + "%";
      document.getElementById(this.str).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
  sortt() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 300; j++) {
        this.str = "bar" + j;
        if (this.arr[j] < this.arr[i]) {
          this.temp = this.arr[j];
          this.arr[j] = this.arr[i];
          this.arr[i] = this.temp;
        }
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
      this.str = "bar" + i;
      document.getElementById(this.str).style.width = this.arr[i] + "%";
      document.getElementById(this.str).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
  }
}
```

here is the code for app.component.html

```
 <div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Open Visualizer</a>
    <a href="#">Technologies Used</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
<section>
    <button (click)="generateArray()">generate array</button>
    <button (click)="sortt()">sort</button>
    <div class="bar" *ngFor="let items of arr; let i=index;" [id]="'bar'+i"></div>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting.

Comment: @Rutvik, document.getElementById is not an "angular way", you can simply use `<div *ngFor="let items of arr" class="bar" [style.width]="items+'%'">`. Think that Angular relate the Model (variables in .ts) with the View (the .html). More about interpolation in the docs:https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: @Eliseo the problem is i dont want the divs to have the width directly set from the tag itself ,i also have transition property in css which makes the arrays load with that transition animation, with your method that thing is not possible

Comment: Well, you can use ViewChildren and create a manual animation -see my answer-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use ViewChildren or ViewChild to get a reference about html elements.

In angular you can create and animate manually. e.g. you can has a function

```
  animate(element:any,width:string)
  {
      const myAnimation = this.builder.build([
        animate(this.timing, style({ width: width })),
        ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(element);
      this.player.play();

  }
```

And, if you has

```
<button (click)="click()">Animate</button>
<div *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3]" #bar 
    style="height:1rem;width:0px;background-color:red;margin-bottom:.5rem">
</div>
```

You can has in .ts

```
  @ViewChildren("bar") bar: QueryList<ElementRef>; //<--here your bars
  timing = "450ms ease-in-out";

  private player: AnimationPlayer;

  constructor(private builder: AnimationBuilder) {}

  click() {
    this.bar.forEach(x => {
      this.animate(x.nativeElement, 100 * Math.random() + "%");
    });
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u56g7f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)